# Call python script to take parameters from the query

Tags: python, html, plone, zope

I have this list of people:

```
<table id="table_list">
  <tr>
    <td  tal:repeat="records context/all_people">
      <div>
        <span tal:replace="records/name">a</span><br>
        <span tal:replace="records/surname"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have this script getInfo(name,surname):

```
result=container.getData(name=request.name,surname=request.surname)
```

the query getData is

`select city, description from getDatiPeople   where name=<dtml-sqlvar name type=string> and surname=<dtml-sqlvar surname type=string>`

I want to select one people of thi table and open a new html page that contains the table with the data (city and description) of the person that I selected.

Comment: Please review the python code since it doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: @uto: Now it's even less informative.

Comment: the python script named getInfo take two parameters (name, surname), execute the query (container.getGata(...))and obtain the result...and iin the result there is city and description...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can get data out of your database. I cannot help there, because the question lacks data or error messages why it wouldn't work.

This is what you should most likely do

- For each people you have an id in database
- You generate a HTML code with this id

  ```
    <a target="_blank" tal:attributes="href string:${portal_url}/@@yourviewname/id=$[records/id}">
     <span tal:replace="records/name">a</span><br>
     <span tal:replace="records/surname"></span>
  ```
- This pop-up link points to a new page template / browser view which takes the person id as a HTTP GET query parameter
- Then in this new view you'll use the person id to query person data again, now with more details
- You print out details in browser view / page template output